# Gridview Filter is not working in android

Tags: android, filter

Hi in the below code Implementaing a search functionality.Gridview is used to display the grid layout .My grid layout is working fine .In that Grid I am searching by name but it is not working .

Example I have three names named as cardiology ,Ent ,Ortho if I am searching or typing ca means giving me exact one cardiology .if I type o means again showing me the cardiology the result should be ortho

can any one help me where I did the mistake

Layout:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:queryHint="Search By Speciality"
                    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
                    app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Fragement.java:

```
 search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.d("TAG","new Text ==>"+newText);
                speclializationAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Adapter:

```
public class SpeclializationAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<DataList> doctorListModels;
private ArrayList<DataList> completeList;
private SpeclializationAdapter.MyItemClickListener clickListener;
private DoctorAdapter.SelectIemClickListner selectIemClickListner;
public SpeclializationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataList> doctorListModels, MyItemClickListener clickListener){
    mContext=context;
    this.doctorListModels=doctorListModels;
    this.clickListener=clickListener;
    this.completeList=doctorListModels;
    this.completeList = new ArrayList<DataList>();
    this.completeList.addAll(doctorListModels);
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return doctorListModels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView = null;
    final ImageView speclialistimage;
    final TextView specialization;
    final LinearLayout speclist;

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = new View(mContext);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.speclialist, null);
        speclialistimage=convertView.findViewById(R.id.specilistimage);
        speclist=convertView.findViewById(R.id.speclist);
        specialization=convertView.findViewById(R.id.specialization);
        specialization.setText(doctorListModels.get(position).getSpecialization());
        // specialization.setText(speclistListFiltered.get(position).getSpecialization());
         final String specliality_name=doctorListModels.get(position).getSpecialization();
         if(specliality_name.equals("Cardiology")){
             speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardiology);
         }
        if(specliality_name.equals("ENT specialist")){
            speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.neurology);
        }
        if(specliality_name.equals("Orthopedics")){
            speclialistimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.orthopedic);
        }

        final View finalGridView = gridView;
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                speclialistimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_button);
                clickListener.myItemClick(position);
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<DataList> searchResult = new ArrayList<DataList>();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < completeList.size(); i++) {
                    if (completeList.get(i).getSpecialization().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        DataList d = new DataList(completeList.get(i).getSpecialization());
                        searchResult.add(d);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                searchResult.addAll(completeList);
            }
            filterResults.count = searchResult.size();
            filterResults.values = searchResult;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            doctorListModels= (ArrayList<DataList>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

public interface MyItemClickListener{
    void myItemClick(int position);


}
```

}

Comment: I wouldn't call the issue `<Some reliable feature> doesn't work in Android` hehe )) Millions of guys use it ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up in reference . Right now your both `ArrayList` i.e `specialistListFiltered` and `doctorListModels` pointing to same object . So any modification you make in one of them affects both.

Where as one list shoould contain all items and other one should contain the filtered item and only filtered List will be used with Adapter.

```
private ArrayList<DataList> doctorListModels;
private ArrayList<DataList> completeList;
public SpeclializationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataList> doctorListModels, MyItemClickListener clickListener){
    mContext=context;
    this.doctorListModels=doctorListModels;
    this.clickListener=clickListener;
    this.completeList = new ArrayList<DataList>();
    this.completeList.addAll(doctorListModels)
}
```

As above i have changed the name to `completeList` just to avoid confusion . Not you will be using complete list during filtering.

```
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
    ArrayList<DataList> searchResult = new ArrayList<DataList>();
    if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
        constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < completeList.size(); i++) {
            if (completeList.get(i).getSpecialization().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                DataList d = new DataList(completeList.get(i).getSpecialization());
                searchResult.add(d);
            }
        }

    } else {
        searchResult.addAll(completeList);
    }
    filterResults.count = searchResult.size();
    filterResults.values = searchResult;
    return filterResults;
}
```

PS you should be already using `RecyclerView` not `GridView` . `ListView` and `GridView` are legacy now .

Comment: it should work . Use updated answer and debug the code .

Comment: if I type c means list is null

Comment: But I am using gridview ,gridview list is coming correctly,Now if type a letter c nothing is showing my gridview

Comment: Please have a look